# Qtip ajax to pick data dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax, tooltip

I have tried the Qtip

```
$the_tooltip= "TEST\nTEST2";

echo "<td id=25 title=".$the_tooltip." >
```

I have this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('[title!=""]').qtip();


    })
```

It is working fine. I have seen the qtip link which talk about ajax but how am I going to pass some ID to my url to get related information.

Secondly how to format my tooltip on next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the following link for more details:
http://qtip2.com/plugins

The ID can be passed in the data attribute of the ajax request as per the name value pairs. For example:
ID = 10
ajax call will look like

```
    $.ajax({
    url:"URL to the link",
    type:"POST or GET",
    data:"ID=10"
    }).done(function(data){
    //print the data for the success result.
    });

//The code to apply mouseenter and mouse leave on each td element.
    var tdElements = $("td");
    $.each(tdElements,function(i,v){
    $(this).on("mouseenter",function(e){
    var idval = $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'Loading...', // The text to use whilst the AJAX request is loading
        ajax: {
            url: '/path/to/file', // URL to the local file
            type: 'GET', // POST or GET
            data: {ID:idval} // Data to pass along with your request
        }
    }
}).done(function(data){

});
            }).on("mouseleave",function(e){
        //Code to behave when the mouse leaves the td element.
        });
        });
```

Comment: MY problem now is how to pass the ID from my td itself? Where to store the ID and how to pick in Qtip function ? Secondly how to ensure I can put them in separate new lines the data?

Comment: Can you please refer to an example in your code so that I can better understand the problem statement ?

Comment: I have updated my question with this $the_tooltip= "TEST\nTEST2";
    
    echo "<td id=25 title=".$the_tooltip." > where I put in the id as 25 and how to capture that id to be pass into my ajax function. Secondly how to ensure the breakline works as I have tried both <br/> and /n not working.

Comment: Is there any event that is happening or you want to do that for each td element on the page ?

Comment: Yes the event will be when I mouse over those td and I prefer the tooltip to be on bottom left rather than bottom right now.

Comment: For the positioning you can refer to the documentation of qTip

Comment: Ok how about the td where I mouse and pass the id. I want only those with td with id set to non-empty value. How about the breakline ?

Comment: I have seen the changes but how to put the whole thing in the qtip();

Comment: Then to set the results of the ajax is this the correct syntax this.set('content.text', data); which should be in this part rite done(function(data){

}); ? How about the break line any idea?

Comment: The reference to the current tooltip will be required you can check the current documentation which is the part of the post to understand that how to set the data for the ajax request for qtip.